# HTML file only displays the last file from python walk

Tags: python, html, image, relative-path, os.walk

I'm working on getting all the images from a directory onto a HTML file using python and HTML. However when using my script below and a user-inputted test folder file path of 10 images (let's name it, C:/example/pictures) only the last image in the input folder is printed on the HMTL file.

In my code, I used a system argument to call for a user inputted file path like C:example/pictures, and then I use the os.walk function and os.path.relpath function to get all the relative paths for each file in the folder. I then create an HTML file from the python script, using the baseName as the header, and display what's supposed to be every photo from the file. Even though the when I run:

```
print relativeFiles
```

It will print all 10 relative paths of the files, when I run the HTML portion of the code, it only displays the last image from the folder instead of all 10.

```
import sys, os
# Image directory or imageD is a user input, C:example/pictures
imageD = sys.argv[1]
baseName = os.path.basename(imageDir)
outputDir = 'C:/pictures' + 'images.html'

file_set = set()
# I used to os.walk function to get the relative path names of all the files under the user input folder, C:/example/pictures
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(imageDir):
    for i in files:
        relativePaths = os.path.relpath(imageD, outputDir)
        relativeFiles = os.path.join(relativePaths, i)
        file_set.add(relativeFiles)
     
 #Now I start my HTML


startHtml = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>'''
middle = '''
        <h1>{0}</h1>
        <img src='{1}' widht ='100' height = '100'>  \n'''.format(baseName, relativeFiles)
end = '''   </body>
</html>
'''

htmlfile = outDir 
with open(htmlfile, 'w') as outf:
    outf.write(startHtml)
    outf.write(middle)
    outf.write(end)
```

When I run the code, the HTML file output only has the last image on the HTML document. How would I need to structure the code so that all 10 photos are printed and not just the last?

Comment: I would use a templating library, but we're not here to give recommendations. Just have a search for "Python HTML templating"

Comment: You need to have a loop so you have a separate `<img ...>` tag for each photo